# Absolute positioned div with aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

The problem is to have parent and child `<div>` elements, both of them responsive with aspect ratio. and child `<div>` size(e.g. width) need to be some percent of parent. and both of them have `position: absolute`

There are 2 ways to set responsive aspect ratio on `<div>` element

> 1. with `vw/vh`
> 2. set padding-top/bottom with % on child element, or pseudo element

1. Problem for first approach: I need to set `<div>` inside responsive(with aspect ratio) `<div>`, when changing parent also changes child size, but `vw/vh` not depends from parent
2. Problem for second approach: setting padding with % on child element not changing height of parent element when parent's position is absolute

I would like to have this only with CSS

Is there any way to do this? Thank you